# Bash splitting filename with space and dash in delimiter

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parsing, delimiter

I have a bunch of files that I have been able to get with the following command (where `EXT` is the extension):

```
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

array=$(find . -iregex '.*\(EXT\)' -print)
for file in ${array[@]}; do
    echo "$file"| cut -f1 -d" - "
done

IFS=oIFS
```

The file name format is like so: `PARTONE - PARTTWO` where part one is any character (but `not a dash [-]`, and part two is any character and can include a dash)

Is there any way to get PARTONE and PARTTWO into their own variables? Currently, (I believe that) due to the space being part of the delimiter it doesn't work and I get the following error `cut: bad delimiter`

Comment: `cut` only accepts single-character delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of many ways:

```
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

array=$(find . -iregex '.*\(EXT\)' -print)
for file in ${array[@]}; do
    PART_ONE=`echo $file | sed "s/ - .*$//"`
    PART_TWO=`echo $file | sed "s/^[^-]* - //"`
done

IFS=$oIFS
```

To remove a `./` prefix from the first part (assuming one always exists):

```
PART_ONE=`echo $file | sed "s/^\.\/\([^-]*\) - .*$/\1/"`
```

And to remove an extension from the second part:

```
PART_TWO=`echo $file | sed "s/^[^-]* - \(.*\)\.[^\.]*$/\1/"`
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Is there a good guide for `sed` on the web?

Comment: Also, how would I remove the first 2 characters (`./`) from `PART_ONE ` and the extension from `PART_TWO` (last 4 characters?)

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth I added a couple of `sed` commends to do that. There are lots of online resources for `sed`. If you learn how to use an editor like `vi`, then `sed` accepts the same kinds of command-line commands. The most powerful part is arguably the regular expression substitution (one description given here: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).